# Measuring length of string in pixel in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I find the length of string in pixels in javascript , if I know the font-size and font-family?

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910407/get-string-length-in-pixels-with-javascript?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353385/how-to-calculate-the-length-in-pixels-of-a-string-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: As there is here a better answer than in related questions, I now vote to reopen.

Comment: @dystroy I think it would make more sense to merge the answers from this question into the question's duplicate, so that all of the answers can be viewed on one page.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create an in memory canvas (i.e. one that isn't added to the DOM) and then use the `measureText` function :

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "11px Arial";        
var width = ctx.measureText(str).width;
```

Comment: After having seen the links, I vote to close as duplicate but please note that my solution is different from the ones in the links (I didn't profile to compare).

Comment: this is nicer solution. The question was posted but the solutions given I found were using jQuery, whereas I do not have to use jQuery

Comment: After having seen the other answers, I agree. I vote to reopen. You can accept this answer if it pleases you better.

Comment: IE8 and prior doest not support canvas, so any better solution?

Comment: You know Google doesn't support IE9 any more ? You might want to review the list of browsers you support.

Answer (score 1):

you can put your string into  paragraph and use the jquery width function to get the width in pixel [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
    function showWidth(ele, w) {
$("div").text("The width for the " + ele +
" is " + w + "px.");
}
$("#getp").click(function () {
showWidth("paragraph", $("p").width());
});
```

[check jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boraganesh/QDb5Y/1/)